# AdSense | Get verification for a 'secret' blog

Tags: google-adsense, blog

> I've posted a similar question (
>   [Hide the relationship between blog articles but still get listed on AdSense](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/127435/hide-the-relationship-between-blog-articles-but-still-get-listed-on-adsense?noredirect=1#comment173500_127435)
>   ) earlier but this is now more relevant, so please give me a note to
>   delete the previous question if you feel it should be removed.

I have a section in my website where I want to publish articles based on my work ( art/design/photography ), promotional materials for local events/businesses and other more national promotional meterial ( plus maybe some personal posts ).

So as you can tell, it's a bit of a random section, meaning that there is no real home page. I simply want people to be able to visit the article directly from social media or 3rd party websites.

The url/links are structured as:

```
http://example.com/articles/id/40294092 ... A local business profile
http://example.com/articles/id/53904930 ... A music event article
```

Meaning that simply visiting `http://example.com/articles` will result in a redirect back to `http://example.com`.

So if I want my `articles` to have AdSense adverts, I obviously need to give the root of my articles, which in this case will result in a blank page, followed by the redirect.

How can I get Google AdSense to verify my url?